# :host:defined doesn't work, :host(:defined) works

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom, pseudo-class, custom-element

Is it not possible, or not allowed, to combine [`:host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host) and [`:defined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:defined) in CSS, while combining the latter with the [`:host()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()) pseudoclass works?

As you can see in below example, the following

```
:host:defined { display: block; }
```

does **not** work, while

```
:host(:defined) { display: block; }
```

works.

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
      :host { display: none; }
      :host:defined { display: block; }  
      `;
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<code>&lt;${this.tagName.toLowerCase()}&gt;</code> connected!`;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}
class OtherCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
      :host { display: none; }
      :host(:defined) { display: block; }  
      `;
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<code>&lt;${this.tagName.toLowerCase()}&gt;</code> connected!`;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
customElements.define('other-custom-element', OtherCustomElement);
```

```html
<custom-element></custom-element>
<other-custom-element></other-custom-element>
```

The above code example on codepen: https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/GRKEGax

Comment: Does `:host :defined` work?

Comment: @Mordred That wouldn't make sense at all, because it's the `:host` that matches `:defined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector) we can read:

> The `:host` pseudo-class, when evaluated in the context of a shadow tree, **matches the shadow tree’s shadow host**. In any other context, it matches nothing
>
> The `:host()` function pseudo-class has the syntax: `:host( <compound-selector-list> )`
>   When evaluated in the context of a shadow tree, it **matches the shadow tree’s shadow host** if the shadow host, in its normal context, **matches the selector argument**. In any other context, it matches nothing.

Basically, `:host` will match the shadow host and nothing more. You cannot combine it with any other selector While the second syntax allow you to add a selector inside `()`.

If you refer to the example shown in the specification:

> say you had a component with a shadow tree like the following:

```
<x-foo class="foo">
  <"shadow tree">
    <div class="foo">...</div>
  </>
</x-foo>
```

> For a stylesheet within the shadow tree:
>
> 1. `:host` matches the `<x-foo>` element.
> 2. `x-foo` matches nothing.
> 3. `.foo` matches only the  element.
> 4. `.foo:host` matches nothing
> 5. `:host(.foo)` matches the  element.

Note the (2) and the (4). (2) is selecting nothing because no common selector can select outside the shadow tree. Only `:host` and `:host()` can do. The (4) is selecting nothing because `:host` is designed to be used alone to select the *shadow host* but if you want to add another selector you have to use `:host()` like in the (5).

Here is a basic example to illustrate:

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
      :host.box { color:red; }  
      `;
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<code>&lt;${this.tagName.toLowerCase()}&gt;</code> connected!`;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}
class OtherCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
      :host(.box) { color:red }  
      `;
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<code>&lt;${this.tagName.toLowerCase()}&gt;</code> connected!`;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
customElements.define('other-custom-element', OtherCustomElement);
```

```html
<custom-element class="box"></custom-element>
<other-custom-element class="box"></other-custom-element>
```

Now the question is: Why we have two kind of selectors when we can simply have `:host` combined with any other selector.

It's to avoid confusion and ambiguity when parsing the selector since the shadow host can only be selected by a special selector. If we write `:host.foo` the browser will try to match the element with `.foo` and `:host` but it will be tricky because `.foo` can only match an element inside the shadow tree while `:host` can go outside so parsing the selector to find if yes or no we have `:host` inside in order to consider the remaining part of the selector to match the shadow host will be tedious.

Using `:host()` make it easy for the browser to parse the selector and `:host` is a particular case of `:host()` with no selector.

> Note: This is different from the specificity of similar pseudo-classes, like `:matches()` or `:not()`, which only take the specificity of their argument. This is because `:host` **is affirmatively selecting an element all by itself**, like a "normal" pseudo-class; it takes a selector argument **for syntactic reasons** (we can’t say that :host.foo matches but .foo doesn’t), but is otherwise identical to just using :host followed by a selector.

Note the *we can’t say that `:host.foo` matches but `.foo` doesn’t*